# How to submit a Haar Cascade to opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier

I have trained a haar cascade for detection of dog faces ,it gives really good accuracy.Is there any way I can submit it to opencv,so that my cascade can be included in list of other cascades? I have always used github projects that's why I would also like to contribute something.

Comment: You can submit a pull request to [https://github.com/opencv/opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv). There is a [contribution guideline](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/How_to_contribute). You can also look at some tutorials if you are not familiar with github.

Comment: Thanks for the help